# Mirror repository to subfolder in another repository

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge, git-push

Assume  I have repository 'A' in gitlab. Developers will often push code changes to repository 'A'.
I have another repository 'B' in same gitlab.I have subfolder 'C' in repository 'B'.Whenever developers commit their changes to repository 'A',I need to reflect exact code change in subfolder 'C' in repository 'B'.
Is this posible in gitlab.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use git submodules.

1. Create the .gitmodules file in the root of the repo B

```
[submodule "Nameofmodule"]
    path = subfolderC
    url = https://gitlab.com/yourrepo (you can also use ssh here)
```

2. Initialize your submodule

`git submodule init`

3. "Get" the data from repo A

`git submodule update`

After that you will see the content of Repo A inside the folder C

I recommend you to read the documentation https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Pay attention, if you are going to use the Gitlab CI, the configuration is a little bit different

```
[submodule "project"]
  path = project
  url = ../../group/project.git
```

The reason and the instructions are here https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/git_submodules.html

Comment: Submodules point to specific git commit. Newer commits to repository A will not reflect in submodules unless I do manually checkout to specific comit. Is there way to reflect any comits to repository A to be reflected in Repository B submodules automatically? Btw thanks Sergio for the feedback